# how to modify the button styling and size

Tags: css

I have the css and html code for a button as given below. the button will be in header..

```
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
          <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-icon="my-map" data-theme="c" data-iconshadow="false">
            <img src='http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131126195004/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/a/aa/Home_icon_grey.png' alt="custom buttom" />
        </a>
```

css code:

```
.ui-icon-my-map {

    background-position: 4px 50%;
    background-size: 16px 11px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-top: -8px !important;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

The button should appear like image instead of button.and how to reduce the size of button to normal home icon size.

Comment: Please, add a JsFiddle of your code (with image) because, personally, I don't understand "button should appear like image instead of button". In addiction.... to size your button, is not enough changing its width and height?

Comment: Please check my answer and send feedback please

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this....

```
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
 <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-icon="my-map" data-theme="c" data-iconshadow="false">
 <img src='http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131126195004/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/a/aa/Home_icon_grey.png' alt="custom buttom" style="height:32px;border:none;" />
 </a>
```

Please comment back if you need/require further help

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-icon="my-map" data-theme="c" data-iconshadow="false" class="home"><img src='http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131126195004/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/a/aa/Home_icon_grey.png' alt="custom buttom"  />
```

```
.home img {
height:35px;
display:block;}

http://jsfiddle.net/Vgcuj/
```